# Select rows by corresponding columns in one table

Tags: sql, join, select, union

I have a simple table:

[image: person table]

I want to return this:

```
PersonID | LastName  |  Boss Name
1 | A | B
2 | B | C
3 | C | D
4 | D | null
```

Basically, one table which has columns corresponding to each other - one row is a Person, Boss is an id of another `Person` (row) who is the boss of that one.

Does anyone know how to select that? It would be easy if those where two tables. It can be multiple selects but I'd prefer to use one (if it's possible). I tried to write inner join on the same table or some union of two selects but can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self-join. You can use the same table twice in the query; you need to assign aliases to them.

```
select t1.PersonId, t1.LastName, t2.LastName
from person t1
left join person t2 on t1.boss = t2.PersonId
```

You need outer join (`LEFT JOIN`) to keep rows with the `null` values in `boss` attribute.

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now! I was missing the aliases. I started to think you cannot join on the same table. Haha thank you very much!